# Rewriting spring context from xml to java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm rewriting my Spring context from XML to Java class, but this bean below I don't know. Can anyone help me? I'm using Spring Boot.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="order" value="10"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property 
              name="properties" ref="externalConfigProperties">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Autowired Properties externalConfigProperties;

    @Bean
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer(){
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setSystemPropertiesModeName("SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE");
        configurer.setOrder(10);
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        configurer.setProperties(externalConfigProperties);
        return configurer;
    }

}
```

Comment: yes - this :)  I initially mistook the properties on the bean as part of the Properties. While I was editing my answer, this answer popped in.

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Spring it is recommended to use a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` instead of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. When defining a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` it should be registered as a `public static` `@Bean` method as mentioned in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

To load your properties add a `@PropertySource` pointing to the location of your properties file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("path/to/your/config.properties")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer configurer(){
        PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer();            
        configurer.setOrder(10);
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);         
        return configurer;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Along these lines:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Properties externalProperties) {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesBean = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertiesBean.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    propertiesBean.setSystemPropertiesModeName("SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE");
    propertiesBean.setOrder("10");
    propertiesBean.setProperties(externalProperties);
    return propertiesBean;
}
```